# How do I set start date with the core date field?

Tags: 8, datetime

I need set the start date (e.g. *now +1*) for my date field. How can I do this on Drupal 8.1.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your field, you have the option of setting a default value.  Set the **Default Value** to **Relative Date** and then ender "+1 day" into the textfield, and proceed with setting up the field.

When you create new entities with that field, it will default to the current time +1 day, which you can then change if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The core date field doesn't support a start and end date, it's a single value field. See [this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/501428) for the nitty-gritty for when the field was originally added, and the [current issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2161337) about adding end-date support.

Date 'range' fields, with the option for a start/end date, are supported by the contributed [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module. Though the D8 version is still in dev so YMMV.